# How to match methods in macros?

Tags: macros, rust

The `item` fragment can match functions, but if the first argument of the function is a variant of `self`, *i.e.* if it is a method, it is not recognized as an `item`:

```
macro_rules! test {
    ( $fn:item ) => {}
}

// Ok
test! {
    fn foo() -> bool {
        true
    }
}

// Not ok
test! {
    fn foo(self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

How to match a method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a macro that contains a match body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329653/writing-a-macro-that-contains-a-match-body)

Comment: @Tyfingr Please can you explain the link between my question and the question/answer you linked because I cannot see it.

Comment: What does `fn foo(self) {} ` mean outside of an `impl` block?

Comment: A fn that takes self is _not_ an item, but its surrounding impl block is.

Comment: @PeterHall It will be put in an impl block. That's for a boilerplate code generator. I'll generate the inherent impl and a trait impl at once.

Answer (score 4):

A function that takes `self` is not an item, because it can't exist at the top level without an `impl` block to give a type to `self`.

The surrounding `impl` block *is* an item though.

To match the function, you'd have to break it down, perhaps like this:

```
macro_rules! test {
    ( fn $fn:ident ( self ) -> $ret:ty $body:block ) => {};
}
```

But you have to use the macro *inside* the `impl` block:

```
impl Foo {
    test! {
        fn foo(self) -> bool {
            true
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to also handle quite a few permutations of possible kinds of function here though, which could end up getting quite repetitive:

```
// enables the ? operator for optional parts
#![feature(macro_at_most_once_rep)]

macro_rules! test {
    ( fn $fn:ident ( $($name:ident : $type:ty),* ) $( -> $ret:ty )? 
        $body:block 
    ) => {};
    ( fn $fn:ident ( self $(, $name:ident : $type:ty)* ) $( -> $ret:ty )? 
        $body:block 
    ) => {};
    ( fn $fn:ident ( &self $(, $name:ident : $type:ty)* ) $( -> $ret:ty )? 
        $body:block 
    ) => {};
    ( fn $fn:ident ( &mut self $(, $name:ident : $type:ty)* ) $( -> $ret:ty )? 
        $body:block
    ) => {};
}
```

And these don't even consider lifetime or type parameters.

Getting code reuse, by delegating these cases to another macro, might be tricky because you don't have the type of  `self` inside the macro, so you might not be able to get rid of the repetition, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible to match all the method with a single fragment? I cannot match the impl block because I need to match separately the generic types and the bounds

Comment: I'll use your solution. It will be simple because the functions signature will be always the same.